# Can anyone translate the Chinese text on the picture attached?

Tags: translation, character-identification

Can anyone translate the Chinese text on the picture attached?

[image]

Comment: I have translated ithe text using YOUDAO!

Comment: you should add that into your question - and detail why it didn't help or what your stuck with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

第一，我们可以看到买家已经安装了产品，我们在发货已经明确告知买家收到包裹后，不要马上安装，一定要先测试再安装，并全程用视频记录，这么做就是为了防止因为买家自己安装错误导致的问题把责任推到我们身上，我们本来就不能控制买家怎么安装！！

第二，从专业的角度分析出现买家视频中的问题有以下因素：１。买家在安装过程中，灰尘进入了排线，而要用牙刷和酒精刷一下排线；２。买家没有扣好排线；３买家在安装过程不小心扯断了排线。

请Aliexpress小组明察，谢谢！！

First, we can see that the buyer had already installed the product, we had notified the buyer upon delivery, not to install it immediately, the buyer should test it before installing, with the whole process being video recorded, this is to prevent buyer from installing it incorrectly and blaming us for responsibility, we can't control how the buyer is going to install it!!

Second, by analyzing buyer's video with problem from professional perspective, the problem occurs with the following reasons: 1. Dust has got into cable during installation, the cable would need to be brushed with toothbrush and alcohol; 2, Buyer does not buckle or connect the line/cable properly; 3. Buyer accidentally broke the cable during installation.

We hope/request that Aliexpress Team will investigate the details clearly to prevent reputation damaging to us. Thank you.*

*The last sentence is a bit long compare to the original sentence as I couldn't come out with a proper word to translate 明察, so I tried to make it understandable.

Hope this helped.